# Time complexity of deterministic select

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Suppose I do k groups. As the size of the input array is not constant, the number of elements in a group will be n/k. Sorting this will take (n/k)log(n/k). For k groups it will be (n)log(n/k) which is
O(nlogn). Then how come the algorithm is of O(n)?

Edit: From Gfg https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array-set-3-worst-case-linear-time/amp/

```
kthSmallest(arr[0..n-1], k)
1) Divide arr[] into ⌈n/5⌉ groups where size of each group 
is 5 except possibly the last group which may have less     
than 5 elements.
2) Sort the above created ⌈n/5⌉ groups and find median 
of all groups. Create an auxiliary array ‘median[]’ and 
store medians of all ⌈n/5⌉ groups in this median array.
// Recursively call this method to find median of 
median[0..⌈n/5⌉-1]
3) medOfMed = kthSmallest(median[0..⌈n/5⌉-1], ⌈n/10⌉)
4) Partition arr[] around medOfMed and obtain its 
position.
pos = partition(arr, n, medOfMed)
5) If pos == k return medOfMed
6) If pos > k return kthSmallest(arr[l..pos-1], k)
7) If pos < k return kthSmallest(arr[pos+1..r], k-pos+l-1)
```

Comment: What do you mean, "do k groups"? And what do you mean by sorting the groups? You need to explain this clearly and specifically.

Comment: "k" is already a parameter of the function, don't use it for something else additionally, that's just confusing.

Comment: Also, they don't do "k groups", they do n/5 groups. You're trying to change the algorithm. If you do then yeah, possibly you have a worse complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sorting the elements in each group, you are only looking for their medians, which is `O(n/k)` (this is theoretically done on small and constant values of `n/k`, which is then just considered as `O(1)`). So you have to run `O(n/k)` algorithm `k` times, which yields `O(n)`.

Note that even if you do sort, since the algorithm uses a **constant** size of groups, then the size of each group: `n/k = C` (for some constant `C`), and you get: `O(nlog(n/k)) = O(nlog(C)) = O(n)`

Comment: It says that the groups need to be sorted. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array-set-3-worst-case-linear-time/amp/

Comment: @user12208242 There is no need to sort, there is no need to sort. See for example more authorative sources: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960130.html, but even with this assumption, for small groups (i.e. constant size) `O(nlog(n/k)) = O(nlog(n/(n/C))) = O(nlogC) = O(n)`.Let me clarify.